# How to recycle my asp.net web application in production server?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, production-environment, recycle

I have made changes to my `global.asax` file so i want to recycle my web application to make the changes work. How to safely recycle my asp.net web application in production server? Any ideas..

Comment: @RPM without affecting the existing application..

Comment: Just upload the new global.asax - the next time a visitor starts a new session, the app will call the new code automatically.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring your suggestion worked please post it as an answer so that i can mark it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upload the new global.asax - the next time a visitor starts a new session, the app will call the new code automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, you can recycle the Application Pool for your application.

In IIS 7: go into Application Pools, right-click your application's Application Pool and click 'Recycle...'.

If you're worried about not killing users' sessions, etc, then I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: No need to recycle the app pool.

Answer (score 1):

Directly upload the asax file over the server instance and it would work as expected.

A new AppDomain would be created when you upload the new global.asax file in the site and this would be used for any new requests arriving at the server and for existing requests the earlier version would remain active as lon as the session's active.